# I have this 3 undefined index error

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined-index

I have this error, and I can't solve it:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\store\header.php** on
>   line **10**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined index: user in **C:\xampp\htdocs\store\header.php** on
>   line **11**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined index: password in **C:\xampp\htdocs\store\header.php**
>   on line **12**

---

I have a login page, where I log in, set the **id**, user and password of the session. And when I log in, everything works fine except for the error that keeps showing.

This is the **`header.php`** :

```
    <?php
    session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
            $msg_logout = '<br />
               <div>                                              
                  <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>              
                </div>';        
            }
          // checking if this SESSION is in the DB
            $userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); 
            $user = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["user"]);
            $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); 
                        // Connect to the MySQL database  
            include "conx_to_db.php"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($db_1,"SELECT * FROM fans WHERE username='$user' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
                        // confirm user in DB
            $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
            $msg_login = "<div>
                     <a href='login.php' style='text-decoration:none; color: #000;'>Login</a> </div>
                 <div id='bt_registar'>
                     <a href='registo.php' style='text-decoration:none; color: #000;'>Registar</a>
                 </div>";
                 }
     ?>
     <div id="head">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo34.png" height="80" border="0">
    </div>      
    <div>
    <?php echo $msg_login; $msg_logout; ?>
        <br /><a href="cart.php"><img   src="img/cart.png" height="56" width="56" style="vertical-align:middle;"><strong>Cart</strong></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the **`index.php`**:

```
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Store test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php include_once("header.php");?>

    <div id="main"> 

<hr>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
        <td width="35%" valign="top" style="border-right:3px solid green">     <h3>&#8226; Service</h3><br /><br />
        <p>Benvindo .</p>
        <p>gets some god stuff.<br /><br />

        <p>&eacute; A store bla bla! <br />
        <br />
            Isto &eacute;  test!</p></td>
        <td width="65%" valign="top"><h3>&#8226; Os mais comprados</h3><br   />
     <p><?php echo $List; ?><br /></p>
                  </td>
    <br />
    <br />
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>

      <?php include_once("footer.php");?>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

I hope someone can explain me what is wrong.
Thank you

Comment: `$_SESSION["id"]`, `$_SESSION["user"]` and `$_SESSION["password"]` are not set

Comment: Hi Afzal, welcome to SO.

Comment: Well i have the Session set on my login page, with id, user and password. Everything works okay when i log in. i forgot to tell that.. i am going to edit the question to add this info.
...Sorry about that

Comment: @Afzal - your login page sets the id, user, and password in `$_SESSION`.  Those indexes won't exist until the page is called. I've added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, these three lines

```
$userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]);
$user = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["user"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]);
```

are the problem.  The script is looking for an `id` address in the `$_SESSION` array, and it's not there for some reason, so it reports that the index is undefined.

To fix it, you can use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) { ... }
```

or make sure that it's set before it's needed.

**EDIT**

Your login page sets the id, user, and password in $_SESSION. Those indexes won't exist until the page is called.

`header.php` needs to know those values though, so either set them ahead of time, or use `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is really simple and PHP already told you what is the error.

All you need is just to read. It is telling you that indecies `id`, `user` and `password` are not defined.

So `$_SESSION["id"]`, `$_SESSION["user"]` and `$_SESSION["password"]` are not defined.

Few words to make your life simpler: do not paste 2 pages of your code. Try to localize the problem, because I assume that you would be downvoted severely.

Answer (score 0):

After some time i got it.

the solution is:

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
      if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['password'])){
        $log = 1;
        }
      }
   }
```

Thanks everyone for your help, i know it looks basic, but i'm a beginner, and learning!

"please note carefully that these are not **errors**! They are **notices**." by James ->Checked

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to initialize a variable:

```
$userID = isset($_SESSION["id"]) ? $_SESSION["id"] : NULL;
```

And after when you are going to do any operation with `$userID` you can check if this is null

```
if(!empty($userID)){
   //do something
}
```

[Assigning a default value using Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues)

Answer (score 0):

Please check you session with given code that session is empty or not

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

what ever its show reply to this i will let you know where is the issue.